# Prepare statemnt using concat() in mysql giving error

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-error-1064

The given below code is part of stored procedure (mysql 5.5.20):

```
prepare stmnt1 from concat('insert into ' , tableName ,  '(employee_id , administrator_id) values(? , ?) ' ) ;                   
set @a = 19 ;
set @b = 11;
execute stmnt1 using @a , @b ;
```

`tableName` is local variable

When i create procedure i get this error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to         
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'concat('insert into ' , 
tableName ,  '(employee_id , administrator_id) values(? ' at line 23
```

It seems that this kind of statement is not possible in mysql.

Please help.Thanks.

Comment: This question needs revival and especially add the prepared-statement option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one please.

```
set @sql = concat('insert into ' , tableName ,  '(employee_id , administrator_id) values(? , ?) ' ) ; 
prepare stmnt1 from @sql;                
set @a = 19 ;
set @b = 11;
execute stmnt1 using @a , @b ;

deallocate prepare stmnt1;
```

Comment: @RaviJain How about some feedback? Is it working now?

Comment: Please tell me who answered the question first of both of you , the one who answered first will be accepted.Both of you have same answer and works fine.Thanks

Comment: @RaviJain Hover with your mouse over "answered yesterday" and you will see a tooltip with the exact time. First was me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use it in a variable

```
set @sql_string = 
concat('insert into ' , tableName ,  '(employee_id , administrator_id) values(? , ?) ' ) ;  
prepare stmnt1 from @sql_string;                 
set @a = 19 ; 
set @b = 11; 
execute stmnt1 using @a , @b ;
```

Comment: Please tell me who answered the question first of both of you , the one who answered first will be accepted.Both of you have same answer and works fine.Thanks